# Javascript or other charting library for geodata

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highcharts, gis

I am working with openlayers and wms. But I have seen charting API like:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart
http://www.highcharts.com/studies/us-map.htm

These APIs generate very nice interface (map based or other) with print option as image or png.

[High chart with print option](http://highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)

I found D3 to be rich library but Highcharts is more interactive (I guess).

http://www.smartjava.org/content/using-d3js-visualize-gis

Which will be the best **charting** option for visualizing **GIS** data? Data that are related to region, boundary and not to custom locations and regions. And also with save option available as image or pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that HighCharts would not be useful at this point. The reason being that the map you link to is an alpha version. It is not in the main trunk of the HighCharts codebase.
There are several other methods to do what you want if keeping with javascript/html5 tech:

- http://www.giscloud.com/
- [ArcGIS Javascript](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm)

Note that ArcGIS is in no way cheap.

Comment: I need something like openlayes that can be stored locally.

Comment: Both of those allow you to store your shape files on your local server. GISCloud also offers options to upload the data to their cloud storage.

Comment: Also, as an aside what you are looking for is probably mapping libraries and not necessarily charting libraries to visualize map data.